# how to insert text into json using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to insert text into json array using jquery/javascript .

supposing I have data as

some numbercodes in a text file format 123, 456, 789

I want to get them in a json array format using javascript/jquery.

```
var nuumbercodes = [ "123","456","789" ];
```

Comment: I don't see any JSON. That's a JavaScript array. Do you want to convert `nuumbercodes` to JSON? You certainly don't want to directly modify JSON with JavaScript. You parse it, modify the data structure and serialize it back.

Comment: YES I want to convert it into JSON array, for example code type1 type2 type3.

Comment: There is some serious confusion with the terminology here. `["123","456","789" ]` is a javascript Array. `JSON`(JavaScript Object Notation) is just a string notation of an Object.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a well formatted text string with comma separated numbers, 
 like this `'123,456,789'`

This should have no spaces or tabs, 
 
Then you can convert it simply into a [JavaScript array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

```
var myTextwithNuumbercodes='123,456,789';

var numbercodes=myTextwithNuumbercodes.split(',');
```

returns ['123','456','789']

if you have a JSON string like this '[123,456,789]' then you get a javascript array by calling JSON.parse(theJSONString)

```
var numbercodes=JSON.parse('[123,456,789]');
```

returns [123,456,789]

notice the "[]" in the string ... that is how you pass a JSON array
toconvert it back to a string you can use `JSON.stringify(numbercodes);`

if you have a total messed up text then it's hard to convert it into a javascript array
but you can try with something like  that

```
var numbercodes='123, 456, 789'.replace(/\s+/g,'').split(',');
```

this firstly removes the spaces between the numbers and commas and then splits it into a javascript array

in the first and last case you get a array of strings
u can transform this strings into numbers by simply adding a + infront of them if you call them like

```
mynumbercode0=(+numbercodes[0]);// () not needed here ...
```

in the 2nd case you get numbers

if you want to convert an array to a string you can also use join();

```
[123,456,789].join(', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a string, then [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it on commas, use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) in a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FStatements#for_Statement) to convert the string numbers into actual Numbers and remove the whitespace, then [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert to JSON.

Comment: Ok, how would i do it for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904286/put-data-from-textarea-into-json-array

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) push values at the end of an array. After that you could use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)(nuumbercodes) to make a [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON) string representation of your Array.